# .htaccess - exclude one domain - can i make it better?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, redirect, server

I have 2 domains,and the .htaccess from the main domain affect the second domain.
I try to exclude the second domain,hours later i think im done.

Please check line 5 and 6

Question: is my code valide ?Is this ok ? Can i make it better ?

```
### RewriteEngine On ###
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
### http -> https ###
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?SECOND-DOMAIN\.com$
RewriteRule ^.*$ '-' [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteRule (.*) https://FIRST-DOMAIN.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
### Rewrite application ###
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
### Close RewriteEngine ###
</IfModule>
<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>
```

*My internet is very slow and i cant check all my pages atm*

Thanks! <3

Comment: Instead of going through all that effort it would have been much easier to place your rewriting rules in the http servers host configurations. That way they are separate and you get rid of the performance penalty from using dynamic configuration files (`.htaccess` style files).

Comment: Hi, no access to this files..is a shared host. I can remove this 2 lines and  force ssl for the second domain on a extra .htaccess   (this works too) but i know which way is better. @arkascha

Comment: why would both domains share the same document root, even on a shared server?